# Matplotlib barra de cores vertical discreta

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz, matplotlib

Criei uma função que imprime matrizes na forma:

```
def PrintColourMatrix (m, title):   
    fig, (ax0) = plt.subplots(1)
    c = ax0.pcolor(m)
    ax0.set_title(title)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.colorbar(c)
    plt.show()
    
    filename = title + '.png'
    fig.savefig(filename)  
    return filename
```

Considere-se uma matriz de entradas aleatórias, definida como

```
m_random = np.array([[round(rd. random(),2) for j in range(n_cols)] for i in range(n_rows)])
```

Neste caso, `n_rows = n_cols = 10`. O aspecto final é o seguinte:

[image: m_random]

No entanto, eu quero fazer a mesma coisa com uma matriz que toma **apenas** os valores [-1, 0, 1] e cujo mapa de cores é dado por **{-1: vermelho, 0: branco, 1: preto}**. A barra de cores vertical, portanto, tem de representar valores **discretos**. Além disso, eu não quero que cada segmento de cor seja associado a um intervalo (ex: vermelho, [-1, 0[ ), mas sim aos valores que indiquei acima, respectivamente (vermelho, -1).

Como faço isso? Já pesquisei muitos sites e fóruns, mas quase todos consideram mapas pré-definidos, com cores que não me interessam. Até agora nenhum me ensinou o método para discretizar a barra de cores.

Comment: Já tentou com [`matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html)?

Comment: Sim, já tentei. Aliás, eu adaptei a função para ter uma barra segmentada e consegui. Mas a origem da matriz muda. Isto é, no eixo horizontal o zero está à esquerda e no eixo vertical o zero está no topo. E eu não sei como desfazer isso. Por outro lado, continuo a ter a barra "em intervalos", isto é, vermelho: [-1,0[, branco: [0,1[ e preto: [1,2[. Quando o que eu queria é que cada segmento correspondesse apenas a um número só (representativo do estado de cada entrada da matriz).

Comment: @AugustoVasques, caso isto que eu quero não seja possível, sugere alguma legenda com o propósito que eu pretendo?

Answer (score 3):

Aqui vai uma solução que se adapta ao número de cores dentro do seu mapa de cores, e que utiliza os valores desse mesmo mapa para gerar uma matriz discreta de tamanho arbitrário.

O segredo está em usar `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list` para criar um Colormap discreto, e usar ele ao plotar a matriz com `plt.imshow`. Esse método retorna um Colormap discreto desde que o argumento `N` seja igual ao tamanho da lista de cores entregue a ele.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

tamanho_matriz = (10, 10)
mapa_cores = {
    -1: '#FF0000',  # vermelho
    0 : '#FFFFFF',  # branco
    1 : '#000000',  # preto
}

N = len(mapa_cores)
valores = list(mapa_cores.keys())
cores = list(mapa_cores.values())

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', cores, N)
matriz = np.random.choice(valores, tamanho_matriz)

plt.imshow(matriz, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar()

# Coloca cada label no meio do respectivo intervalo de cor
largura_cor = (max(valores) - min(valores)) / N 
posicoes = np.linspace(min(valores) + largura_cor/2, max(valores) - largura_cor/2, N)
cbar.set_ticks(posicoes)
cbar.set_ticklabels(valores)

plt.show()
```

Figura resultante:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como comentei, a solução se adapta a qualquer `tamanho_matriz` e `mapa_cores` utilizado. Por exemplo, com os valores:

```
tamanho_matriz = (3, 7)
mapa_cores = {
    -3.3: '#FFFF66',
    15  : '#0123FF',
    7.2 : '#0F5AED',
    0   : '#1291AB',
}
```

Geramos a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom, é isso que eu quero. Mas como consegue colocar o zero do eixo vertical na base da matriz? Isto é, ter as coordenadas (0, 0) no canto inferior esquerdo?

Comment: Isso acontece porque, pela notação padrão, matrizes / imagens são lidas de cima pra baixo. Então Y=0 corresponde à parte superior da imagem. Para modificar isso, adicione o argumento `origin='lower'` ao chamar `plt.imshow`.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigada pela ajuda!